# UITableViewCell subviews report incorrect width when using size classes

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

For some reason, when using size classes in xcode 6, I am getting incorrect widths for subviews in my cell. I have a `UIImageView` with autolayout for sizing (constant: 10 for top, L/R, bottom).

When calling the following from `tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)`:

```
println("w: \(cell.mapSnapshotImageView.bounds.size.width) h: \(cell.mapSnapshotImageView.bounds.size.height)")
```

I always get:

```
w: 580.0 h: 80.0
```

Even though it **should** be `w: 300.0 h: 80.0` based on my 320x100 cell on an iPhone 5S.

Everything displays correctly, but I want to use the width of the subview for some calculations for other subviews. Any ideas as to why this is happening? Bug report or working as designed?

**EDIT:**

This issue only applies to cells that are loaded initially. When cells are reused, the issue does not present itself. `println` output on reused cells:

```
w: 300.0 h: 80.0
```

Comment: Do you get the same inconsistency if you check in `willDisplayCell:atIndexPath:`?

Comment: Same result, `w: 580.0 h: 80.0`

Comment: Funny... Try those lines: `println("w: \(cell.contentView.frame.size.width)")`, `println("w: \(cell.contentView.subviews[0].frame.size.width)")`. The result is quite surprising.

Comment: Interesting. The contentView returns an appropriately sized frame, but not the subviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also ran into this issue. When you dynamically change the size of the views the subviews need to update their values accordingly. You are referencing the values before they have been updated.

My work around was to reference the values after they had been updated. In this case it was in viewDidAppear(). Hope this provides some use. I spent a while trying to figure it out.

Comment: Will take a look, sorry for the delay!

Comment: this is the only way I've been able to consistently get the correct cell size. On a NavigationController push, it won't fire until the slide in animation is finished which is annoying

Comment: Late "Accept", wanted to close the loop on this. It's just a weird workflow.

Answer (score 32):

Call `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` in `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` before accessing the frames. That will do the trick.

Comment: ohh...BEFORE is a key :)

Comment: It dint work hence I had to reload the tableView in viewDidAppear() method.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was getting the bounds of a view in the `layoutSubviews` method but I forgot to call `[super layoutSubviews]`. So, my code looks like blow

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews]; // this line to add
    self.layerToAdd.frame = self.viewContainer.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try in the method layoutSubviews(), after calling [cell layoutIfNeeded]  to get "right" values for the subviews.

Comment: This does not work. I am trying to set only top corner radius on one of subview of content view of uitableviewcell. I am doing this inside overridden layoutSubViews method. Only works on second time loading of that particular cell.