# UITableViewCell size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, user-interface

I have a table view with cells in my IOS app. The thing is that when the cell loads I need to layout some stuff on it that is relative to the size of other elements. The problem is that I can't get the size because there is no viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad methods, which have actual bounds(with autolayout and constraints applied). What is the best way to work with cell's geometry and sizes in IOS, can somebody tell me ?

Comment: This answered the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28837935/4665643

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Auto Layout and self-sizing cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights) (in iOS 8).

The layout system will determine the size of the "stuff" in the cells, and proper constraints will then determine the cell's height.